# Determine which files have at least a particular number of lines matching a pattern

Tags: regex, shell, text-processing, ls, fasta

I'm looking for a way to identify [FASTA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FASTA_format)-files with at least 3 sequences. Sequences are identified by lines starting with `>`.

Here is an example of 5 files:

file1

```
>sp1
ATTTT
>sp3
ATTGG
>sp3
ATTGAGGAGA
>sp4
AGGGGAGGACC
>sp5
AGGGGGG
>sp5
AGGGGGG
```

file2

```
>sp1
ATTTT
```

file3

```
>sp1
ATTTT
>sp3
ATTGG
>sp3
ATTGAGGAGA
>sp4
AGGGGAGGACC
>sp5
AGGGGGG
```

file4

```
>sp1
ATTTT
>sp3
ATTGG
```

file5

```
>sp1
ATTTT
>sp3
ATTGG
>sp3
ATTGAGGAGA
>sp4
AGGGGAGGACC
>sp5
AGGGGGG
```

I want the output:

```
file1
file3
file5
```

since those are the files with at least three sequences.  Can I do this with `ls`?

Comment: The `ls` command cannot operate that way of looking into the file content and make a decision to list the file entry or not. That's not what is designed to do, it just lists the directory contents with attributes if asked for it. You need other commands to identify the count and then print the file if condition matches

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do the job :

```
grep -Hc '^>' * 2>/dev/null | awk -F':' '$2 > 3 {print $1}'
```

How it works :

- `grep -Hc '>' *` counts lines having a '>' in everything ('*')
- the `2>/dev/null` suppresses error messages because `grep`-ing on `*` also matches directories and causes an error
- for every match, `grep` outputs `fileName:n`, n being the number of matches found
- then Awk is taught to read the second field of every line ('$2'), and if this is greater than 3 (the `$2 > 3` part), display the file name, which is the first field of the line (i.e. `$1`)
- the `-F':'` part instructs awk what is the field separator

Comment: where is the part where I tel the minimum number of '>' wanted

Comment: It's `$2 > 3` Change 3 to the minimum number. @chippycentra

Comment: You should use the `-H` option so that it always prints the filename, even if there's only one file.

Comment: this will fail if filenames contain colons.

Comment: This will fail if the line starting with `>` contains another `>`

Comment: @oguzismail and kvantour : you both are right, and this might be fixed with extra checks / different commands. But these specific constraints are not in the OP's question.

Comment: @Httqm The specifications are not directly written down, but the OP is working with FASTA files and is actually asking to identify the files with 3 sequences in it. Each sequence is identified by a line starting with `>`.  You can just update your line from `>` to `^>`

Comment: @kvantour Indeed ;-) (I'm no specialist of FASTA format). I've edited my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Using GNU awk:

```
$ awk '(FNR==1){c=3}/^>/{c--}!c{print FILENAME; nextfile}' *
```

This will not process the full file, but just enough to determine whether or not the fasta-file has 3 or more sequences:

- Every time we enter a new file, the file-record number `FNR` is reset to 1. If this happens, we reset the counter `c` to 3.
- Every time we see a line starting with `>` we decrement the counter
- If we encountered `3` sequences (recognized by `c==0`), we print the FILENAME and move to the next file.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a Perl one-liner, for two reasons: the question is interesting; and the question triggered me to learn more about Perl!

```
perl -ne '++$count if /^>/; $count=0, close ARGV, print "$ARGV\n" if $count==3' *
```

- `perl -ne`: Don't print the lines as they are processed; run the following code
- `++$count if /^>/;` - count the lines that start with `>`.  `$count` starts out undefined, and Perl's `++` treats that as `0`.
- `$count=0 ... close ... print ... if $count==3`: Once we see the third line starting with `>`, reset `$count` and do the `close` and `print`.

  - `close ARGV`: Don't process any more lines in the current file
  - `print "$ARGV\n"`: print the name of the file we have just finished processing.  `$ARGV` is the name of the current file and doesn't reset until it's time to process the next line.  See the "Perl-like pseudo code" in [`perlop`'s I/O operators section](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2FO-Operators).

**Edit** By the way, Perl actually has library support for FASTA in [BioPerl](https://metacpan.org/release/BioPerl) and other modules.  See, e.g., https://metacpan.org/search?q=FASTA .